# Why we do what we aren't allowed to do

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, terminology, brain

Don't touch the red button, or don't touch that chocolate cake while I'm gone. Why is it that we most likely will touch them anyway?

Comment: I saw something a while ago on this (a study or something) and I cannot remember right now what it was.  I hope to be able to find it.

Comment: I think its because, doing something unexpected (breaking the rules) gives a sense of being free. Doing something unusual, makes them feel that they doing something new, novel, which gives them some pleasure.